# UK Accident and Emergency Roles

Tags: emergency, trauma, emergency-room

I need some help with a novel I'm writing.

My character is a highly-experienced surgeon, working on a UK Accident and Emergency ward, who also trains those coming up through the ranks.

In a USA ER, as I understand it, a trauma surgeon would have a team of residents and interns beneath them who they train. The interns being complete newbies and residents having completed their internship.

What are the equivalent roles in a UK A&E?

Presumably, the titles aren't the same?